# Firebase - Get signed in user's detail and sign out the user in another activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a `LoginActivity` where user signs in to my app via Firebase (sign in with Google). How to *access and update* the signed-in user's details in other activity. Also how to *sign out* the user in the next or other activity.

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SignInButton signInButton;
private GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient;
private String TAG = "Login Activity";
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
SharedPreferences sp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    signInButton = findViewById(R.id.btnSignInGoogle);
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    sp = getSharedPreferences("login", MODE_PRIVATE);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();



    if (sp.getBoolean("logged",false)){
        gotoMainActivity();
    }else {
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signin();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void signin() {
    Intent signInIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask){
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount acc = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        //Signed In Successfully
        FirebaseGoogleAuth(acc);

    } catch (ApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Sign In Failed
        FirebaseGoogleAuth(null);
    }
}

private void FirebaseGoogleAuth(final GoogleSignInAccount acct) { //To handle firebase google authentication
    AuthCredential authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) { //checking authentication credential and checking successful or not
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Success
                FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // Fail
                updateUI(null);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser fuser) {
    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
    if (account != null){
        gotoMainActivity();
        sp.edit().putBoolean("logged", true).apply();
    }
}

private void gotoMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseUser user;
Button btnSignOut;
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnSignOut = findViewById(R.id.btnSignInGoogle);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            user.signout();
        }
    });

}}
```

I want to sign out the user in MainActivity. And I want to access and update all the details about the user in MainActivity and other activities in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to sign out the user in MainActivity.

You can **not** call `signout()` on a FirebaseUser object, you should call it on a `FirebaseAuth` object like this:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signout();
```

> And I want to access and update all the details about the user in MainActivityand other activities in the future.

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();
if(user != null) {
    Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
    updates.put("fieldName", "fieldData");
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("users").document(uid).update(updates);
}
```

In this way you can update a field name of type String in user document in Cloud Firestore.